# socket.io - html page scroll down when emit

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, jquery-mobile, socket.io

I've noticed strange behavior on my page. 
Im using jquery mobile + socket io.

When checkbox is being checked Im sending message via socket io and page is being automatically scrolled down to the bottom.

When I comment out socket.emit... it works as expected. 
What can be a root cause of that ?
Thanks in advance

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var socket = io();

    $(':checkbox').change(function() {
        var state = $(this).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
        var command = $(this).attr('id') + ";" + state;
        socket.emit('message', command);
        console.log(command);
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you subscribed to the socket and waiting for events in any part of your code?

Comment: yes I was and there was a bug - thanks for hint!!